# MySQL Query of Column Based on Alternative Column

Tags: mysql

I’ve trawled through a number of conditional MySQL type questions online but haven’t come across anything that helps with this query, it’s likely I’m describing the question incorrectly in my internet search, however, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Assume I have a table titled `results` with the three columns outlined below how do I query the table for all teammates of `James`? I know I can query `WHERE Team = 'B'`, however, if I don’t know the team name, how do I get all teammates of James?

```
Team     Name   Place
A        John   1
B        James  2
B        Harry  3
C        Brad   4
```

What I want to return is the following:

```
Team     Name   Place
B        James  2
B        Harry  3
```

Is a two query type approach required, where I first query the team name for `James` and then use the output of that query to undertake a second query?

Comment: Why not sit down with any basic book or tutorial? It will be of fantastic benefit.

Comment: Couldn’t agree more on the tutorials and I tried to find something with worked examples but I was obviously classifying the question incorrectly. Rest assured, my first port of call is to always try work these things out for myself first.

Comment: But can you now see that this is just a basic join?

Comment: Totally agree. Imagine how much time I wasted on this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM results t1 where t1.Team IN
  (SELECT t2.Team FROM results t2 WHERE t2.Name='James')
```

OR

```
SELECT t1.* FROM results t1
   JOIN results t2 on t1.team=t2.team
where t2.name='James'
```

Comment: Let's start with the second suggestion

Comment: Thankyou very much for this, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` operator

```
SELECT * FROM results as t1 
where  t1.team in (SELECT team FROM results  WHERE name='James')
```